# after upgarding mysql to 5.7 SHOW PROCESSLIST not showing all active processses anymore

Tags: mysql

AWS upgarded our database from 5.6 to 5.7 (5.7.38).
Since that update a lot of our queries are performing very porly due to the query-optimizer using the wrong indexes.

In order to identify and optimize those queries I'm using the "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" query but I noticed that not all requests are being listed.

I'm also able to reproduce when running a slow query locally from our backend-applications and then checking the responde of "FULL PROCESSLIST" that slow query is not showing at all.

Any idea why that is? is there maybe some configuration that could be done? (I'm logged in with the admin-user)

Comment: doing some more isolated testing by only executing that one slow query via our application and doing nothing else.

And it is showing in the PROCESSLIST for the first 50ish seconds but then not anymore (according to our app the query was running for over 108sec)
-> this number was always very accurate and identical to what I saw in MySQL 5.6)

The query itself is super simple (returning 100,000 records):
SELECT `id`, `type_id` FROM `vehicle_base_models`;

running this query in heidiSQL it only takes 3 sec (most of it being network)

Any idea where this difference is coming from?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm lost -- If it takes only 3 sec, how come it showed up for 50?